# Vue.js - global shared state and for loop outside component - is this good practice?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.JS. I was trying to achieve two list of books (readed and not readed), the books list is a shared object (on global data state).

This is my solution  - [working demo](https://repl.it/repls/WigglySecondhandOpensoundsystem) (**it works!** But I'm asking myself is this is considered a good practice, and I have some questions that maybe you can help to clarify)

The HTML:

```html
<div id="root">
  <h2>Books pending to read</h2>
  <ul>
    <book-li 
      v-for="book of notReadedBooks"
      :key="book.id"
      :book="book.title"
      :status="book.readed"
      @changeit="changeStatus(book.id)">
    </book-li>
  </ul>

  <h2>Readed books</h2>
  <ul>
    <book-li 
      v-for="book of readedBooks"
      :key="book.id"
      :book="book.title"
      :status="book.readed"
      @changeit="changeStatus(book.id)">
    </book-li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```js
Vue.component('book-li', {
  props: [ 'book', 'status' ],
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ book }} – <button @click="$emit('changeit')"> {{status ? 'will reread' : 'readed'}} </button>
    </li>
  `
})


const App = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    allBooks: [
      { title: 'El Aleph', id: 101, readed: true },
      { title: 'Ficciones', id: 102, readed: false  },
      { title: 'La torre de Babel', id: 103, readed: false  },
    ]
  },

  computed: {
    readedBooks: function() { return this.allBooks.filter( singleBook => singleBook.readed )},
    notReadedBooks: function() { return this.allBooks.filter( singleBook => ! singleBook.readed )},
  },

  methods: {
    changeStatus(idCurrentBook) {
      let bookIndex = this.allBooks.findIndex(book => book.id === idCurrentBook)
      this.allBooks[bookIndex].readed = ! this.allBooks[bookIndex].readed
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see I loop through 2 computed lists (readed and not readed), but I tried to render this in a better way. For example:

1 - I wasn't unable to pass the whole readed/unreaded list to the component and then define a component with the `v-for` loop inside.

Something like `<book-list :list="readedBooks"></book-list>`
and then inside that component do a `v-for` with the `list` prop. Is that possible on Vue or the loop should happen outside the component?

2 - Another problem I found, if I rename the `:book` attribute bind as `:book-title` then Vue tells my I need to define a `:book` attribute, even if I'll not use it (?).

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

### EDIT:

Thanks to @luca-faggianelli to give me some insight.

I manage to create a `v-for` loop inside and so I could simplify the code a lot:

```html
<div id="root">
  
  <h2>Books pending to read</h2>
    <books :list="notReadedBooks"></books>

  <h2>Readed books</h2>
    <books :list="readedBooks"></books>

</div>
```

```
Vue.component('books', {
  props: [ 'list' ],
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li v-for="book in list">
      {{ book.title }} - <button @click="book.readed = !book.readed">{{ book.readed ? 'read again' : 'readed' }}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    allBooks: [
      { title: 'El Aleph', id: 101, readed: true },
      { title: 'Ficciones', id: 102, readed: false  },
      { title: 'La torre de Babel', id: 103, readed: false  },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    readedBooks: function() { return this.allBooks.filter( singleBook => singleBook.readed )},
    notReadedBooks: function() { return this.allBooks.filter( singleBook => ! singleBook.readed )},
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to get started reading something about Vue Components https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Then answering your questions:

1. it makes creating a `<book-list>` component and sure you can have for loops inside a component
2. you must rename `book` attribute in the component declaration, that is, in:

```
Vue.component('book-li', {
  props: [ 'bookTitle', 'status' ],
```

then you can use `:book-title`, notice that Vue wants kebab-case props in the HTML and camelCase in the JS

Comment: Thanks! I manage to get the v-for loop inside the component (I added an EDIT now on the main post, with a much better simplified version of the website!!) 

I don't know why I couldn't get the `v-for` loop before. Maybe I was setting props without the `:` or `v-bind:` syntax (?)